# How to get glassfish/javaee application version?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

Good day.
I deploy some test application with version, as in 
https://community.oracle.com/blogs/serli/2010/08/30/how-use-glassfish-application-versioning

$ asadmin deploy --name=test:BETA-1.1 test.war

But when I try to get application name
http://javahowto.blogspot.ru/2009/12/how-to-get-module-name-and-app-name.html

initialContext.lookup("java:app/AppName") - It returned without version.
Is it possible to get a version of the application programmically?

$ asadmin list-applications
prints appplication names with versions

Comment: Does this one cover your question: http://blog.payara.fish/deploying-multiple-application-versions-on-payara-server ? (Payara is based on Glassfish).

Comment: simdevmon, its just show multiversion deployments. Not say how to get current application version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a place in source where it get AppName:

glassfish3\glassfish\modules\container-common.jar!com/sun/enterprise/container/common/impl/**JavaModuleNamingProxy**.class

```
  private String getAppName() throws NamingException {
    ComponentEnvManager namingMgr = (ComponentEnvManager)this.habitat.getComponent(ComponentEnvManager.class);

    String appName = null;
    if (namingMgr != null) {
      JndiNameEnvironment env = namingMgr.getCurrentJndiNameEnvironment();

      BundleDescriptor bd = null;
      if ((env instanceof EjbDescriptor)) {
        bd = ((EjbDescriptor)env).getEjbBundleDescriptor();
      } else if ((env instanceof BundleDescriptor)) {
        bd = (BundleDescriptor)env;
      }
      if (bd != null) {
        Application app = bd.getApplication();
        appName = app.getAppName();  // <-- HERE!
      }
    }
    if (appName == null)
      throw new NamingException("Could not resolve java:app/AppName");

    return appName;
  }
```

and Application.getAppName() set in createApplication

glassfish3\glassfish\modules\dol.jar!com/sun/enterprise/deployment/**Application**.class

```
  public static Application createApplication(Habitat habitat, String name, ModuleDescriptor < BundleDescriptor > newModule) {
    Application application = new Application(habitat);
    application.setVirtual(true);
    if ((name == null) && (newModule.getDescriptor() != null)) {
      name = ((BundleDescriptor)newModule.getDescriptor()).getDisplayName();
    }
    String untaggedName = VersioningUtils.getUntaggedName(name);
    if (name != null) {
      application.setDisplayName(untaggedName);
      application.setName(untaggedName);
      application.setAppName(untaggedName);
    }
    newModule.setStandalone(true);
    newModule.setArchiveUri(untaggedName);
    if (newModule.getDescriptor() != null) {
      ((BundleDescriptor)newModule.getDescriptor()).setApplication(application);
    }
    application.addModule(newModule);
    return application;
  }
```

As you can see it doesnt save tagged name inside application. Why not use displayName?
Nevertheless, I'll try find another way to get version info...  may be set/read glassfish-application.xml/version-identifier

**Update:** glassfish create folder with version in (domain|node)/applications/appName~version. So we can analyze some resource path :)

```
static final Pattern APP_VER = Pattern.compile("/applications/([^~/]+)(?:~([^/]*))?");

public String getAppVersion() {
  URL res = getClass().getResource("/META-INF/somefile.xml");
  if (res != null) {
    Matcher ver = APP_VER.matcher(res.getPath());
    if (ver.find())
      return ver.group(2);
  }

  return null;
}
```

Have fun! Maybe someone have more beautiful solution?